# Can I use my BiBox without a battery?

Tags: power-supply

I am having trouble using my BiBox developing platform after its battery charging module got damaged due to lightning.

The platform has got a USB microB charging port.
I am wondering if there's a way to use it by directly plugging it to the mains with my phone's charger.

[image]

NOTE: I an OK with the platform being wired in during usage.

Comment: Are you sure it was the battery that was damaged?  Lightning usually damages electronics ratherbthan batteries.

Comment: @JRE It is the circuitry of the charger actually. But the charger module they provide is costly.